# Taking whole string as query parameter spring jpa

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to take a string parameter as query value in spring jpa for postgresql ?

What I'm trying to do is:

```
@Query(value="?1", nativeQuery = true)
double foo(String query);
```

This gives me an error starting like this:

> SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601    ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"

Comment: Can you include the entire query you are trying to run?

Comment: No you cannot... Placeholders only work in a `WHERE` clause. s

Comment: use entitymanager